# Application protection against forced shutdown (Kill App)

Tags: android

I have an application that:

- activates Google Maps navigation when a certain button is clicked
- meanwhile, the Service starts and downloads and sends the site to the server
- Floating Widget also opens (floating widget above all applications - allows you to go back to the application)

The user clears the memory sometimes. I wish that when the widget and the Service are running, I would not be able to do a kill on the application.

I have already tested various solutions and none works.

Starting with `startForegroundService()`

I think Floating Widget makes it difficult to do this somehow

I mean **Clear All**

[image]

Comment: "The user clears the memory sometimes" -- what does "clear the memory" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare Clear All, I mean. I added a screen from the documentation

Comment: Have you tried granting Admin rights to the app? when the application is an Admin running it will not be forced to stop.